# HTTP 503 Error while using python requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, request, http-status-code-503

I'm trying to make a HTTP request but the website that I currently can reach from my Firefox browser response 503 error. Code itself is really simple. After some search in the net I added `user-Agent` parameter to request but it didn't help either. Can someone explain me how to get rid of this 503 error?
Btw I want to make my own alert system based on prices of btc.

```
import requests

url = "https://www.paribu.com"
header ={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; Win64; x64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0 '}


response = requests.get(url,headers = header)
print(response)
```

Comment: 503 is service unavailable. In this case, it looks like the web page has a buffer screen which prevents you from scraping

Comment: 503 appeared on my first try. So I assume they didn't put me on the blacklist, I think as you said they blocked web scraping somehow.

Comment: I have the same issue. Using curl works fine, requests from Java and Chrome also work fine. So I think there is an issue in requests module.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem. Use this in your code.

> ```
> headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36',}
> r = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
> r.raise_for_status()
> ```

[Found from Reddit's /r/learnpython subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/4eaz7v/error_503_when_trying_to_get_info_off_amazon/)

Comment: thx, looks like they are blocking scrapers :)

Answer (score -2):

503 means the server is overloaded:
https://httpstatuses.com/503

This is not an issue with your code, it is an issue with the server you are trying to access.

Comment: It doesn't mean the server is overloaded. It just means that the server is unavailable

Comment: But I can reach the website via my browser. Does not that mean server is OK?

Comment: Not necessarily. It returns 503 because they want to prevent you scraping the site

Answer (score -3):

Status code 503 means that the server is down for maintenance. Just try again later.